# JPA generating an invalid column

Tags: jpa-2.0, generated-code

Helo there.

I am attempting to a execute a many-to-many get all query.  To be clear, I am attepmting to get a collection within a collection to be pulled back.  Ie, we will get a result set, but in that result set, there will be a collection of all objects linked to it via a foreign key.  Now, to do this, I have a collection which I annotate thusly...

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="QUICK_LAUNCH_DISTLIST",
                joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="QUICK_LAUNCH_ID"),
                inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="LIST_ID"))
private Collection<QuickLaunchDistlist> distributionLists;
```

Which seems to be just about text book... 
I call a named query which looks like this...

```
@NamedQuery(name="getQuickLaunch", query = "SELECT q FROM QuickLaunch q")
```

Which is executed like so...

```
qlList = emf.createNamedQuery("getQuickLaunch").getResultList();
```

Every time I make this call, I get back the expected data in the first collection.  But none of the collections seem to populate with it.  To find out why, I looked at the sql being generated by the call... This is what I find...

I get this exception...

```
This is a FFDC log generated for the Default Resource Adapter from  source:com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.executeQuery
The exception caught:java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "T1"."QL_DISTLIST_ID": invalid identifier

SQL Error Code is 904 SQL State is :42000
```

Along with this query...

```
SELECT t1.QL_DISTLIST_ID, t2.LIST_ID, t2.CREATE_DATE, t2.CREATE_USERID, t2.description, t2.flag, t2.MOD_DATE, t2.MOD_USERID, t2.ORGANIZATION_ID, t2.owner, t2.STATUS_ID, t1.MESSAGE_TYPE_ID, t1.MOD_DATE, t1.MOD_USERID, t1.QUICK_LAUNCH_ID FROM EPCD13.QUICK_LAUNCH_DISTLIST t0, EPCD13.QUICK_LAUNCH_DISTLIST t1, EPCD13.DISTRIBUTION_LIST t2 WHERE t0.QUICK_LAUNCH_ID = ? AND t0.LIST_ID = t1.QL_DISTLIST_ID AND t1.LIST_ID = t2.LIST_ID(+)
```

If you look at the first column it request's to pull back you will notice that it selects t1.QL_DISTLIST_ID... Problem is, I have no such named column any where in my db!?!?!?  Why on earth is that column being called?  How does JPA generate the queries that it calls?  If I knew that, I might be a little closer to figuring out what went wrong here or what I did wrong.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.